# Propagandas nos App Android

Tags: android, app, google

Existe algum plugin do Google para colocar anúncios nos aplicativos Android, e com isso ganhar alguma valor?

Comment: aqui tem as formas recomendadas pela google de monetizar sua app: http://developer.android.com/training/distribute.html

Comment: olha isso: http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe o DoubleClick For Publishers (DFP) que é do Google.

O SDK dos anúncios para celular do Google é a geração mais recente na publicidade para celular do Google. Ele oferece formatos de anúncios refinados e APIs simplificadas para acesso a redes de anúncios para celular e soluções de publicidade. Com o SDK, os desenvolvedores de aplicativos para celular podem maximizar a geração de receita nas plataformas Android (como parte do Google Play Services ou do SDK independente), iOS e Windows Phone 8.

No site developers do Google você pode fazer o download do SDK e aprender como integrar.